# JS: How to recognise if a mouse event is provided by touch (not mouse)

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, touch, mouse

I would like to manage mouse and touch events separately even on hybrid devices.

How to disable mouse events (click, mousedown, up...) **or** detect if the event is provided by mouse or touch.

Currently when I touch an object it produces: 
- touch start
- mouse enter (unwanted)
- mouse down (unwanted)

Thank you for an advice :)

Comment: Where are you stuck? How far have you got? Can you should what you have? You just need to track touch events and ignore mouse events between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

Prevent default in the touchstart:

```
$key.on("touchstart", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then the mouse events won't be called.